# Why aren't the rightmost digits zeros (C/Linux)?

Tags: c, floating-point

If you print a float with more precision than is stored in memory, aren't the extra places supposed to have zeros in them? I have code that is something like this:

```
double z[2*N]="0";
...
for( n=1; n<=2*N; n++) {
  fprintf( u1, "%.25g", z[n-1]);
  fputc( n<2*N ? ',' : '\n', u1);
}
```

Which is creating output like this:

`0,0.7071067811865474617150085,....`

A float should have only 17 decimal places (right? Doesn't 53 bits comes out to 17 decimal places). If that's so, then the 18th, 19th... 25th places should have zeros. Notice in the above output that they have digits other than 0 in them.

Am I misunderstanding something? If so, what?

Comment: @UmNyobe The code is unusual but safe I think.  Array elements are dereferenced using [n-1] which gives the same effect as running the loop [0..2*N)

Comment: oh yeah didnt spot that.

Comment: You define z1 but never initialize it, and print z ... you will get better answers if you post code you actually ran. As for misunderstanding something ... yes, *everything* about floating point. Search SO, there's a lot of good material.

Comment: "A float should have only 17 decimal places (right? " - did you mean double??? double - provide 17 digits of precision

Comment: Try http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: A `float` or a `double` or any IEEE-754 floating point representation has no decimal place, only binary ones. Conversion between binary and decimal explains your issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, 53 bits means that the 17 decimal places are what you can *trust*, but because base-10 notation that we use is in a different base from which the double is stored (binary), the later digits are just because 1/2^53 is not exactly 1/10^n, i.e.,

1/2^53 = .0000000000000001110223024625156540423631668090820312500000000

Comment: The IEEE 754 floating-point standard defines a floating-point number to represent **exactly** the value defined by its sign, exponent, and significand. The number of decimal digits you can trust depends entirely on how you have produced a number, not on the number of decimal digits that roughly approximate 53 bits. If you produced the number by exact means, then **every** decimal digit in the conversion of the value to decimal can be trusted. If you produced the number by bad approximations with many rounding errors, then few or none of the decimal digits can be trusted.

Comment: `fprintf` cannot have any knowledge of how many digits can be trusted, and it ought to print the value as precisely and accurately as possible, to avoid introducing new errors.

Answer (score 4):

The string printed by your implementation shows the exact value of the double in your example, and this is permitted by the C standard, as I show below.

First, we should understand what the floating-point object represents. The C standard does a poor job of this, but, presuming your implementation uses the IEEE 754 floating-point standard, a normal floating-point object represents **exactly** (-1)<sup>s</sup>•2<sup>e</sup>•(1+f) for some sign bit s (0 or 1), exponent e (in range for the specific type, -1022 to 1023 for double), and fraction f (also in range, 52 bits after a radix point for double). Many people use the object to **approximate** nearby values, but, according to the standard, the object only **represents** the one value it is defined to be.

The value you show, 0.7071067811865474617150085, is exactly representable as a double (sign bit 0, exponent -1, and fraction bits [in hexadecimal] .6a09e667f3bcc<sub>16</sub>). It is important to understand the double with this value represents exactly that value; it does not represent nearby values, such as 0.707106781186547461715.

Now that we know the value being passed to `fprintf`, we can consider what the C standard says about this. First, the C standard defines a constant named DECIMAL_DIG. C 2011 5.2.4.2.2 11 defines this to be the number of decimal digits such that any floating-point number in the widest supported type can be rounded to that many decimal digits and back again without change to the value. The precision you passed to `fprintf`, 25, is likely greater than the value of DECIMAL_DIG on your system.

In C 2011 7.21.6.1 13, the standard says “If the number of significant decimal digits is more than DECIMAL_DIG but the source value is exactly representable with DECIMAL_DIG digits, then the result should be an exact representation with trailing zeros. Otherwise, the source value is bounded by two adjacent decimal strings L < U , both having DECIMAL_DIG significant digits; the value of the resultant decimal string D should satisfy L ≤ D ≤ U, with the extra stipulation that the error should have a correct sign for the current rounding direction.”

This wording allows the compiler some wiggle room. The intent is that the result must be accurate enough that it can be converted back to the original double with no error. It may be more accurate, and some C implementations will produce the exactly correct value, which is permitted since it satisfies the paragraph above.

Incidentally, the value you show is not the double closest to sqrt(2)/2. That value is +0x1.6A09E667F3BCDp-1 = 0.70710678118654757273731092936941422522068023681640625.

Answer (score 0):

There is enough precision to represent `0.7071067811865474617150085` in [double precision floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format). The 64 bit output is actually [3FE6A09E667F3BCC](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/)

The formula used to evaluate the number is an exponentiation, so you cannot say that `53` bits will take `17` decimal places.

EDIT:
Look at the example below in the wiki article for another instance:

```
 0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125
=2^(−54) × 15 5555 5555 5555 base16
=2^(−2) × (15 5555 5555 5555 base16 × 2^(−52) )
```

Comment: @spin_eight number evaluation is an exponentiation with terms 2^(-i), which means the minimum decimal digit is given by 2^(-53) as user1816548 precised.

Comment: @spin_eight: Per the IEEE 754 floating-point standard, the binary floating-point value with sign 0, exponent -1, and implicit significand (not mantissa) bits 0x6A09E667F3BCD, represents **exactly** 0.7071067811865474617150085 and no other value. This is precisely defined in the standard.

Comment: @spin_eight I am talking about how the mantissa is evaluated. Each digit `i` enable a term `2^(-i)`. Thus, the least significant digit enable the term `2^(-53)` which will be the smallest precision possible.

Comment: @spin_eight: That is not a sentence, and I do not know what you mean. If you were trying to interpret the sign, exponent, and significand (mantissa is the wrong term) I presented, then you may have done so incorrectly. The sign 0, exponent -1 (actual, not biased), and significand 0x6a09e667f3bcc (I had the last digit wrong, used sqrt(2)/2 instead of the sample value), represents exactly (-1)^0 * 2^-1 * 0x1.6a09e667f3bcc, which is exactly 0.7071067811865474617150085. The IEEE 754 standard defines it to mean exactly this and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for float, but in your code appears double.

Anyway, neither float or double have always the same number of decimals. Float have assigned 32 bits (4 bytes) for a floating point representation according to IEEE 754.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format):

> [image: float representation]
>
> The IEEE 754 standard specifies a binary32 as having:
>
> - Sign bit: 1 bit
> - Exponent width: 8 bits
> - Significand precision: 24 (23 explicitly stored)
>
> This gives from 6 to 9 significant decimal digits precision (if a
>   decimal string with at most 6 significant decimal is converted to IEEE
>   754 single precision and then converted back to the same number of
>   significant decimal, then the final string should match the original;
>   and if an IEEE 754 single precision is converted to a decimal string
>   with at least 9 significant decimal and then converted back to single,
>   then the final number must match the original).

In the case of double, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) again:

> [image: double representation]
>
> Double-precision binary floating-point is a commonly used format on
>   PCs, due to its wider range over single-precision floating point, in
>   spite of its performance and bandwidth cost. As with single-precision
>   floating-point format, it lacks precision on integer numbers when
>   compared with an integer format of the same size. It is commonly known
>   simply as double. The IEEE 754 standard specifies a binary64 as
>   having:
>
> - Sign bit: 1 bit
> - Exponent width: 11 bits
> - Significand precision: 53 bits (52 explicitly stored)
>
> This gives from 15 - 17 significant
>   decimal digits precision. If a decimal string with at most 15
>   significant decimal is converted to IEEE 754 double precision and then
>   converted back to the same number of significant decimal, then the
>   final string should match the original; and if an IEEE 754 double
>   precision is converted to a decimal string with at least 17
>   significant decimal and then converted back to double, then the final
>   number must match the original.

On the other hand, you can't expect that if you have a float and print it out with more precision that the really stored, the rest of digits will fill with 0s. The compiler can't imagine the tricks you are trying to do.